# Is there any analogue for ClassDefinition in Angular 7+?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am migrating angular v4 project to a Angular 7. I have faced legacy code and i I can not get rid off that. It has ClassDefinition interface whereas new Angular 7 does not have it.
How can I deal with this problem? 
Example of code is shown below.

I have tried to find out solutions in changelogs of angular documentation but it did not help me at all.

```
import { ClassDefinition} from "@angular/core";

let componentDefinition: ClassDefinition = {
    constructor: MenuItem
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you talk about this: https://v4.angular.io/api/core/ClassDefinition - the first option would be to just declare it in your module:

```
/**
 * Declares the interface to be used with {@link Class}.
 *
 * @stable
 */
export type ClassDefinition = {
  /**
   * Optional argument for specifying the superclass.
   */
  extends?: Type<any>;

  /**
   * Required constructor function for a class.
   *
   * The function may be optionally wrapped in an `Array`, in which case additional parameter
   * annotations may be specified.
   * The number of arguments and the number of parameter annotations must match.
   *
   * See {@link Class} for example of usage.
   */
  constructor: Function | any[];
} &
{
  /**
   * Other methods on the class. Note that values should have type 'Function' but TS requires
   * all properties to have a narrower type than the index signature.
   */
  [x: string]: Type<any>|Function|any[];
};
```

After that, you would need to decide how to deal with a situation based on your code base, but what you should know- is that API was marked as stable but then it was deleted by https://github.com/angular/angular/commit/cac130eff9b9cb608f2308ae40c42c9cd1850c4d#diff-635fe23be5795132e3385c8f4899dc3a

As you can see - the reason was:

> This mode doesn’t
>   allow build tools like Webpack to process and optimize the code, which
>   results in prohibitively large bundles. We are removing this API
>   because we are trying to ensure that everyone is on the fast path by
>   default, and it is not possible to get on the fast path using the ES5
>   DSL. The replacement is to use TypeScript and `@decorator` format.

So you should refactor your legacy code and use TypeScript in the end.